# Why is there a no column name for car names in mtcars dataset in R?

Tags: r

I had a question regarding `mtcars` dataset in R. All the columns have names except first column,that contains Car names such as Toyota Corolla, Mazda. Is there any specific reason for it. If yes, I would like to know the reason. Also, I was wondering if we can do same for one specific column in our own dataset ? If so how ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are the row names for the data.  See

```
rownames(mtcars)
```

You can assign a character vector `vec` as your own row names to a data set `data`, with

```
rownames(data) <- vec
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled on this missing invisible  column, it's killing my mind, absolutely hard to get why, especially if you're beginner.
It's clearly says that it's 11 column, but what column has value 'Mazda' ??

```
    mtcars
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
str(mtcars)
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...

colnames(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
#!!!!! where is name for MODEL ???????

# tried to name columns so there is 11 of them ???
colnames(mtcars) <- c('model', 'mpg', 'cyl', 'disp', 'hp', 'drat', 'wt', 'qsec', 'vs', 'am', 'gear', 'carb')
> colnames(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to that column if necessary.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% as_tibble(rownames="cars")
View(mtcars)
```